# when i try to add the data into table it showing type error

Tags: angular

```
**Component Code**

   export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'position', 'office', 'salary'];
  error: string;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Employee>;

  @ViewChild('table', { static: true }) table: { renderRows: () => void; };
  index = this.dataSource.data.length;
  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList()
      .subscribe((data: Employee) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee>(data);

        console.log(this.dataSource)
      }, (error) => this.error = error)
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form)
      form.reset();
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
      _id: "",
      name: "",
      position: "",
      office: "",
      salary: null
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.value._id) {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.dataSource.data.push(Employee[this.index++])
        this.table.renderRows()
        this.resetForm(form);

      });
    }
    else {
      this.employeeService.putEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);

      });
    }
  }


}
```

When iam trying to add data to a material table through renderRows() method here type  error TS2345: Argument of type 'Employee' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Employee[]'. coming why it's coming i don't know can any help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your subscribe is reciving an Employee array. So this should be like this:

```
this.employeeService.getEmployeeList()
  .subscribe((data: Employee[]) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee[]>(data);    
      console.log(this.dataSource)
}, (error) => this.error = error)
```

Comment: here Employee is the model 

export class Employee {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  position: string;
  office: string;
  salary: number;
}

Comment: But, getEmployeeList return a simple employee? I don't think so. Maybe the problem is about it.